# with two inputs on a form, how can I put CSS in the second input?

Tags: html, css

I created a form to subscribe to a news-letter on my site. So, I have two inputs: one for the email, and the other a check-box.

I want to do CSS in the checkbox, but I don't know how. I left the HTML, the CSS, and a picture:

```css
.info_section .info_form form input {
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.info_section .info_form form button {
  padding: 8px 35px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #171717;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.info_section .info_form form button:disabled {
  padding: 8px 35px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #888888;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.info_section .info_form form input .checkbox {
  padding: 8px 35px;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
  <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Introduza o seu E-mail" required>
  <button type="submit" id="register" disabled>Subscrever</button>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="agree" onclick="checkMe()" />Aceito a <a href="Privacidade.html"> Politica de Recolha, processamento e uso de dados pessoais do utilizador.</a>
</form>
<span id="msg"></span>
```

[My picture of the news-letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wqtq.png):

[image]

PS. Can you help me to put the text in line with the checkbox?

I tried to create a class to the check box like I show on code; and I tried to use the `id` of the checkbox in the CSS too.

Comment: "*I want to do CSS in the checkbox*" - what exactly are you trying to do? I read your CSS but, since it doesn't work, I can't use that to guess at your intent.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve your problem. See this example:

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .info_section {
            background-color: #2d2d2d;
            padding: 30px;
            width: 374px;
        }

        .info_section .info_form form input[type="email"] {
            outline: none;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        .info_section .info_form form button[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .info_section .info_form form button {
            padding: 8px 35px;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            background: #171717;
            margin-top: 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .info_section .info_form .term{display: block;margin-top: 20px;color: #fff;}
        .info_section .info_form .term a{text-decoration: none;}
        .info_section .info_form form input[type="checkbox"]{
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .info_section .info_form form button:disabled {
            padding: 8px 35px;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            background: #888888;
            margin-top: 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .info_section .info_form form input .checkbox {
            padding: 8px 35px;
            position: relative;
            left: -50px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="info_section">
        <div class="info_form ">
            <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
                <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Introduza o seu E-mail" required>
                <button type="submit" id="register" disabled>Subscrever</button>
                <span class="term">
                    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="agree" onclick="checkMe()" />Aceito a <a
                    href="Privacidade.html"> Politica de Recolha, processamento e uso de dados pessoais do
                    utilizador.</a>
                </span>
            </form>
            <span id="msg"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There css selectors. research more on nth-child.

Here is a start: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/.

The easiest way is to wrap the code in a class.

HTML:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
  <div class="class-name">              
   <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Introduza o seu E-mail" required>
   <button type="submit" id="register" disabled >Subscrever</button>
   <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="agree" onclick="checkMe()"/>Aceito a <a href="Privacidade.html"> Politica de Recolha, processamento e uso de dados pessoais do utilizador.</a>
</div>
</form>
<span id="msg"></span>
```

CSS

```
.class-name input[type=checkbox]{
  // Style checkbox
}
```